# Incomplete graph

Tags: c++, graph, brute-force

I have the adjacency matrix of a graph. I wish to calculate the number of hamiltonian paths.
I know the brute force approach tests all N! permutations. However, I am unable to code it, I tried searching but couldn't find a possible approach. 
I was looking for help for the simple brute force approach.

Thanks.

Comment: If there is an edge between `a` and `b` then `graph[a][b] = graph[b][a] = true`. You assign 0, which is false.

Comment: My input is the vertices which are not connected. The rest are all connected.
The code is giving me a compilation error.

Comment: You are missing declaration of `i` variable in for loops.

Comment: prog.cpp:4:57: error: use of parameter outside function body before ']' token
     long long cnt_fin_hp_r(int v,int x,int n, bool graph[][n],int parent[])
                                                         ^
     prog.cpp:4:58: error: expected ')' before ',' token
     long long cnt_fin_hp_r(int v,int x,int n, bool graph[][n],int parent[])
                                                          ^
prog.cpp:4:59: error: expected unqualified-id before 'int'
 long long cnt_fin_hp_r(int v,int x,int n, bool graph[][n],int parent[])
These are the errors I am getting.

Comment: You cant put `n` in parameter declaration when it is one of the parameters. Just pass `bool** graph`

Comment: Edited. I have this error. 
       prog.cpp: In function 'int main()':
       prog.cpp:52:46: error: cannot convert 'bool (*)[n]' to 'bool**' for                                argument '2' to 'long long int hampath(int, bool**, int*)'
          printf("%lld\n",hampath(n,graph,parent));

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99617/discussion-between-someone1-and-nick).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99721/discussion-between-someone1-and-nick).

Answer (score 1):

See my implementation I just did:

Also check this [Hamilton cycle implementation](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/backtracking-set-7-hamiltonian-cycle/) to get some insights how it's done.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define NUM_VERTICES 4

bool graph[NUM_VERTICES][NUM_VERTICES] = {
    {0, 1, 0, 1},
    {1, 0, 1, 1},
    {0, 1, 0, 0},
    {1, 1, 0, 0},
};
int parent[NUM_VERTICES];

bool fin_hp_r(int v, int n)
{
    // If all vertices are connected
    if (n == NUM_VERTICES)
        return true;

    // For all neighbours
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_VERTICES; ++i)
        if (graph[v][i] && parent[i] == -1)
        {
            parent[i] = v;
            if (fin_hp_r(i, n + 1))
                return true;
            parent[i] = -1;
        }

    return false;
}

bool find_hamilton_path()
{
    memset(parent, -1, sizeof(int) * NUM_VERTICES);

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_VERTICES; ++i)
    {
        parent[i] = i;
        if (fin_hp_r(i, 1))
            return true;
        parent[i] = -1;
    }
}

int main(void) {
    find_hamilton_path();
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_VERTICES; ++i)
        printf ("%d -> %d\n", parent[i], i);
    return 0;
}
```

And this one for counting number of all Hamilton paths:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define NUM_VERTICES 4

bool graph[NUM_VERTICES][NUM_VERTICES] = {
    {0, 1, 0, 1},
    {1, 0, 1, 1},
    {0, 1, 0, 0},
    {1, 1, 0, 0},
};
int parent[NUM_VERTICES];

long long cnt_fin_hp_r(int v, int n)
{
    // If all vertices are connected
    if (n == NUM_VERTICES)
        return 1;

    // For all neighbours
    long long res = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_VERTICES; ++i)
        if (graph[v][i] && parent[i] == -1)
        {
            parent[i] = v;
            res += cnt_fin_hp_r(i, n + 1);
            parent[i] = -1;
        }

    return res;
}

long long find_hamilton_path_number()
{
    memset(parent, -1, sizeof(int) * NUM_VERTICES);

    long long res = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_VERTICES; ++i)
    {
        parent[i] = i;
        res += cnt_fin_hp_r(i, 1);
        parent[i] = -1;
    }

    return res;
}

int main(void) {
    printf("%lld\n", find_hamilton_path_number());
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This really helped. However, I am inputting the graph (via adjancency matrix), so I tried to modify my code so it takes in the parent, and graph as parameters, but it is having a lot of issues that way. I'll add my code, if you think that would help.

Comment: If you are just counting number of different Hamilton paths, parent can be just set or array of booleans names `seen_vertices`. Or you can add boolean instance value to each vertice. It's needed not to take same vertex multiple times.

Comment: That is fine, but passing the graph as a parameter is an issue. I am adding the modifiction to your code. Please see that.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem from an ongoing contest
https://www.codechef.com/JAN16/problems/SEAKAM